# Rails API PATCH , what if i just update using GET instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, httprequest

So this is my first API i am developing. I am creating some sort of LIKE and UNLIKE function on my app on android. I understand that we would use GET to just get a response of records , and PATCH to update a specific record. But i had a funny idea that , what if i pass the values through a GET request URL? Example ;
    \voteposts:voteposts_id:choice\
    \voteposts\2\"upvote"\
    \voteposts\2\"downvote"\

then in the controller i would just grab the :choice value and just do the update and return a success message if it succeeds.

Comment: You might notice in the `ruby-on-rails` tag info, it notes that Rails is known for its "convention over configuration" approach. While you could do what you describe, why would you? It's entirely unconventional. I would recommend that you just do things they way they are meant to be done.

Comment: What jvillian said. Also there may be cases where you don't necessarily want your params to be in the form of query params and want them in a POST body instead

Comment: thanks guys, its cause technically i thought it IS possible. but i was wondering if i was missing a huge point if i did this. And in short, it definitely was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes i could do what i mentioned, but its unconventional and its bad practice and habit to have, overall.